# Will an OLAP cube process data if there is no Partition for that data?

Tags: sql-server, multidimensional-array, partitioning, olap-cube

We recently discovered that one of our cubes aren't showing any data for 2023. I eventually discovered that the cube itself only has partitions set up to the end of 2022. I am currently setting up partitions to run through 2024, but I am unsure if this is why no data shows up for 2023. So, If there does not  exist a partition for 2023 timeframes (whether they be quarters or months etc) does the cube just disregard data that falls outside of any specified partition range or does it just append that data to the most recent partition (as is what happens in Sql Server relational tables) or does the cube do something completely different?

There is data for 2023 in the source views, and the cube is fully processed by a Sql server agent job on  a nightly basis, so if you have other ideas about why data is missing I'm all ears.

Comment: The cube will read whatever the partition is configured to read. If no partitions exist that select data from 2023, then yes, you'll get no data from 2023. Whether this happens depends on how you configure the query for the source data: it is certainly possible to leave the partition query open-ended so that the 2022 partition would have 2022 data plus whatever comes after 2022-12, but it's more complicated to maintain when partitions need to be added. Whether you'd rather have missing data or much longer processing times is up to you; proper automation should make the issue moot.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, the partitions are set up to pull for specific time keys, all of which exclude data for 2023. So, it would seem that is the likely culprit.